# specific col_type = col_double when number have comma and point, no trailing characters error

Tags: r, readr

I have squared data in a txt file with "|" separator data with value like this

```
no| value
1|  3,123.00
2|  1,122.75

import it with this code:
library(readr)
data <- read_delim("file.txt", "|", trim_ws = TRUE, locale = locale(decimal_mark = "."), col_types = cols(no = col_double(),
value = col_double()))

Warning: 2 parsing failures.
row    col  expected               actual   file
  1 value   no trailing characters ,123.00 'file.txt'
  2 value   no trailing characters ,122.75 'file.txt'
```

This make the data imported to be NA, I already spesified the local to point decimal mark.

Why are my values read like this: `,123.00` ?, the first number before comma is missing If i specify `col_types` with `col_double`. it works without col_types spesified but i really need to specify the col_types

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it in two steps: read `value` as string and then cast to numeric.

```r
library("tidyverse")
library("readr")

file <- "
no| value
1|  3,123.00
2|  1,122.75
"

x <- read_delim(
  file, "|", trim_ws = TRUE,
  col_types = cols(value = col_character())) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(value), parse_number)
x
#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#>      no value
#>   <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1 3123 
#> 2     2 1123.

# Are fractions missing? No they are not.
x$value
#> [1] 3123.00 1122.75
```

<sup>Created on 2019-03-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: With this solution the decimal value is missing

Comment: No, it is not missing. It is not printed out.